# VaadinServiceInitListener not picked up in a Quarkus app

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, vaadin-flow

I have a Quarkus application using current versions of Vaadin Flow and Quarkus (23.2.4 and 2.13.1.Final). I want to have a `VaadinServiceInitListener` to check access annotations on the views (`@RolesAllowed(...))` using `AccessAnnotationChecker`. I believe annotating the implementation with `@VaadinServiceEnabled`
should fix this, but I need to register it in `META-INF/services/com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServiceInitListener` to have it activated. This is how to do it when not using a dependency injection framework. Then everything works as expected and I can use `AccessAnnotationChecker` to see if the user has access to that view, on `BeforeEnterEvent`.

I also notice the message `Can't find any @VaadinServiceScoped bean implementing 'I18NProvider'. Cannot use CDI beans for I18N, falling back to the default behavior.` on startup. Strangely, implementing `I18NProvided` in a class and annotating it with `@VaadinServiceEnabled` and `@VaadinServiceScoped` makes that message go away, eg. it is recognized by CDI.

Why isn't my `VaadinServiceInitListener` implementation recogized? Currently it is annotated with

```
@VaadinServiceEnabled
@VaadinServiceScoped
@Unremovable
```

My pom.xml include

```
vaadin-quarkus-extension,
quarkus-oidc,
quarkus-keycloak-authorization,
vaadin-jandex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a listener, you can use a CDI event.
Quarkus's dependency injection solution is based on CDI, so you can use the same events. Here's an example

```
public class BootstrapCustomizer {

    private void onServiceInit(@Observes
            ServiceInitEvent serviceInitEvent) {
        serviceInitEvent.addIndexHtmlRequestListener(
                this::modifyBootstrapPage);
    }

    private void modifyBootstrapPage(
            IndexHtmlResponse response) {
        response.getDocument().body().append(
                "<p>By CDI add-on</p>");
    }
}
```

More information here https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/integrations/cdi/events

Comment: Thanks @Marko C, that worked just fine. Doesn't explain why my first approach didn't, but I'll settle for this :-)